Kendo MVC grid Command buttons Not Saving in setOptions
I have a Kendo MVC grid that uses Command Buttons. These buttons use the .Visible function to call a JS function that returns true/false to determine if it is visible.
I am also using getOptions/setOptions to save and restore the grid filtering, grouping, sorting, col. resizing, etc.
The issue is that the setOptions/getOptions do not seem to be saving the .Visible code?
I'm using version 2020.3.915
Is this something the newer versions support?
If not does anyone know of a workabround?

The .Visible function not being saved by getOptions and setOptions is due to the fact that these methods do not serialize JavaScript functions. This is a known limitation because JSON.stringify cannot serialize function references, which means any functions, including those used in .Visible, will be lost when the grid state is saved and restored setoptions methods.
Possible workload

Custom Serialization:

You can implement a custom serialization method to handle JavaScript functions. This involves manually saving the function references separately and reattaching them after deserialization

Reapply functions after deserialization:

Store the grid options without the functions, and then reapply the functions after the options are deserialized. For example:
var gridOptions = grid.getOptions();
localStorage.setItem("gridOptions", JSON.stringify(gridOptions));

// Later, when restoring
var options = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gridOptions"));
options.columns.forEach(function(column) {
    if (column.field === "yourField") {
        column.visible = yourVisibilityFunction;
    }
});
grid.setOptions(options);



Upgrade to newer versions:

While the core limitation with JSON.stringify remains, newer versions of Kendo UI might offer improved methods or additional features that could simplify handling such scenarios. It might be worth checking the latest documentation or release notes for any enhancements related to state management.

JavaScript Initialization:

Instead of using the MVC wrapper, you can initialize the grid using JavaScript. This approach gives you more control over the grid’s configuration and might help in preserving the function references.
